# Translating Imagemagick script to magick.net

Tags: c#, magick.net

I am struggling to translate this cartoon Imagemagick script to Magick.net:

```
%IM%convert ^
  %SRC% ^
  +repage -depth 8 -selective-blur 0x5+10%% ^
  ( -clone 0 ^
    -level 0x60%% -colorspace gray -posterize 6 -depth 8 -gamma 2.2 ^
    -blur 0x1 ) ^
  ( -clone 0 -clone 1 -compose multiply -composite ^
    -modulate 100,150,100 ) ^
  ( -clone 0 -colorspace gray ) ^
  ( -clone 3 -negate -blur 0x2 ) ^
  ( -clone 3 -clone 4 -compose colordodge -composite ^
    -evaluate pow 4 -threshold 90%% -statistic median 3x3 ) ^
  -delete 0,1,3,4 ^
  -compose multiply -composite ^
  out.jpg
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how cloning works and more specifically in compositing two cloned images. The fact is that the result is a full black image and not sure where I am mistaking. Any help will be appreciated. My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage();
            string photo = "Angelita2.png";  //"20170613_122820.png"; 
            string file = @"c:\Fotos\" + photo;
            image = new MagickImage(file);
            
            // +repage -depth 8 -selective-blur 0x5+10%% ^
            image.RePage();
            image.Depth = 8;
            image.SelectiveBlur(5, 10, 1);

            //( -clone 0 -level 0x60 %% -colorspace gray - posterize 6 - depth 8 - gamma 2.2 -blur 0x1 )
            MagickImage cloned0 = new MagickImage();
            using (IMagickImage clone0 = image.Clone())
            {
                clone0.Level(new Percentage(0), new Percentage(60));
                clone0.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.Gray;
                clone0.Posterize(6);
                clone0.Depth = 8;
                clone0.GammaCorrect(2.2);
                clone0.Blur(0, 1);
                cloned0 = new MagickImage(clone0);                
            }

            //( -clone 0 -clone 1 -compose multiply -composite -modulate 100,150,100 )            
            cloned0.Composite(cloned0, CompositeOperator.Multiply);
            cloned0.Modulate(new Percentage(100), new Percentage(150), new Percentage(100));
            //cloned0.Write(@"c:\Fotos\Cartoon\image3.png");

            //( -clone 0 -colorspace gray )
            cloned0.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.Gray;

            //( -clone 3 -negate -blur 0x2 )
            MagickImage clonedIm3 = new MagickImage();
            using (IMagickImage cloned3 = cloned0.Clone())  //(IMagickImage cloned3 = image.Clone())
            {
                cloned3.Negate();
                cloned3.Blur(0, 2);
                clonedIm3 = new MagickImage(cloned3);
            }

            //( -clone 3 -clone 4 -compose colordodge -composite -evaluate pow 4 - threshold 90 %% -statistic median 3x3 )
            clonedIm3.Composite(image, CompositeOperator.ColorDodge);            
            clonedIm3.Evaluate(Channels.All, EvaluateOperator.Pow, new Percentage(4));
            clonedIm3.Threshold(new Percentage(90));
            clonedIm3.Statistic(StatisticType.Median, 3, 3);

            clonedIm3.Write(@"c:\Fotos\Cartoon\image4.png");
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the original command line script? It is a copy from one of my scripts. If you are using it for commercial purposes, then licensing will be required. Note that it is already converted to Magick.NET. See https://github.com/dlemstra/FredsImageMagickScripts.NET

Comment: fmw42, I am sorry. My intention it is not to copy anyone, just trying to learn. Your scrips, in my opinion, are a good place for those as me who are learning imagemagick in c#.

Comment: `@Dumar Linares` If for personal use, then you are fine. Licensing is not needed. Good luck in your endeavor.